# 'profile_update' hook alternative for WooCommerce user meta data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, user-meta, profiles

I am trying to get all user details (including WooCommerce meta data) in a function that is called with `user_register` and `profile_update` hooks. This is the simplified code:

```
function get_all_user_data($user_id) {

    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);

    $login = $user_data->user_login;

    $b_firstname = get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_first_name', true);

}
add_action('user_register','get_all_user_data');
add_action('profile_update','get_all_user_data');
```

**The behavior:**

1. User is registered, I can access it's userdata (e.g. login) immediately
2. WooCommerce billing address is updated and saved, however I still only can access the $login variable, 'billing_first_name' meta is apparently still empty at this time
3. WooCommerce shipping address is updated and saved, after this I can access the billing information that were saved in previous step, but not the shipping data that was saved in current step

The same goes for a scenario in which the user is registered during WooCommerce checkout, no WC data is accessible at that time yet.

PS: I have also tried the `woocommerce_after_save_address_validation` hook, but that seems to have the same behavior as the `profile_update` in my case.

**Edit:** `edit_user_profile_update` doesn't work as well. Setting the action priority to a high number (executed later) doesn't help either. `insert_user_meta` filter works, but only returns native WP's user meta, not WooCommerce customer's meta.

Comment: what I understand is you need to access the data before the save process, right? 
I think this action can help `edit_user_profile_update`
here are the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/

Comment: @AhmadWael same behavior as `profile_update` action from my original solution. The WC customer data is not yet accessible at the time of the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working. The key was the `woocommerce_update_customer` action. In the end my function was triggered only by these two actions:

```
add_action('user_register','get_all_user_data', 99);
add_action('woocommerce_update_customer','get_all_user_data', 99);
```

I don't need the `profile_update` because I don't need to track changes in default WP's user data. However it can be used along with woocommerce_update _customer, but keep in mind your function will be triggered twice.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be this:

```
function get_all_user_data($user_id) {

    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);

    $login = $user_data->user_login;

    $customer_array = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
    $customer = $customer_array->get_data();
    $billing_first_name = $customer[billing][first_name];
    $shipping_first_name = $customer[shipping][first_name];
}
add_action('user_register','get_all_user_data');
add_action('profile_update','get_all_user_data');
```

The array setup for the Customer arrays [billing] and [shipping] is as so (you can just change my values and get different data or add more variables if you'd like):

```
    [billing] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [company] => 
            [address_1] => 1338 Easy St
            [address_2] => 
            [city] => Oakland
            [postcode] => 48094
            [country] => US
            [state] => CA
            [email] => johndoe@example.com
            [phone] => 6167783456
        )

    [shipping] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [company] => 
            [address_1] => 1338 Easy St
            [address_2] => 
            [city] => Oakland
            [postcode] => 48094
            [country] => US
            [state] => CA
        )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution has the same problem. WooCommerce customer meta data is not yet accessible at the time of the `user_register` and `profile_update` actions.

Comment: Update: `insert_user_meta` filter works, but only returns native WP's user meta, not extended WooCommerce billing and shipping details.